# When forking a project, how do you pull to get latest?

Tags: git, github

On github, if I fork a project, how can I then pull the latest from the original project that I forked?

I am essentially creating a duplicate of the forked project, I am assuming this is a manual process I have to do each time there is a change in the forked project right?

Comment: I assume you mean, how does the forked repo on github update from the original? Is that correct?

Comment: **Please review and approve an answer.**

Answer (score 2):

I'll take [Symfony 2 repository](http://github.com/symfony/symfony) as example.
Assuming you have forked it:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```